# workingdirectory does not work when verb is used

Tags: powershell, windows-10

Using `Start-Process`, when `Verb` is used, the `Workingdirectory` option does not work, the new powershell always start in `C:\WINDOWS\system32`. Why is this? How can I do this without an extra `cd` command?

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.0
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.0
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1


PS C:\> Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -Verb Runas -WorkingDirectory C:\ws\

# the new ps shell always in system32:

Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> pwd

Path
----
C:\WINDOWS\system32
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**As for the *why*** - **see the bottom** of this answer.

As for an **effective workaround** (which does, however, require use of `cd` (`Set-Location`)):

```
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -Verb Runas `
  -ArgumentList '-NoExit -Command "cd C:\ws"'
```

To avoid quoting headaches you can also pass the arguments individually, except for the command string itself:

```
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -Verb Runas `
  -ArgumentList '-NoExit', '-Command', 'cd C:\ws'
```

[Venryx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2441655/venryx) points out that if you want to **apply this technique to calling a *script file*** that is normally called with `-File` rather than `-Command`, you must switch to a `-Command` approach (given that the two parameters cannot be combined) that changes the location first and then (`;`) invokes (`&`) the script, `script.ps1` in the new location, this example:

```
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -Verb Runas `
  -ArgumentList '-Command', 'cd C:\ws; & .\script.ps1'
```

For a more complex example involving nested quoting, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57033941/2441655).

---

In practice - and the [docs do not mention that](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx?) - **the `-WorkingDirectory` parameter is *not* respected if you start a process *elevated* (with administrative privileges, which is what `-Verb RunAs` - somewhat obscurely - does): the location defaults to `$env:SYSTEMROOT\system32`** (typically, `C:\Windows\System32`).

<sup>Note that this is not the `-Verb` parameter per se that's the problem, but its specific `RunAs` argument.</sup>

**The *only* case in which `-WorkingDirectory` *is* respected in combination with `-Verb RunAs` is if the program being started is PowerShell *Core*, namely `pwsh.exe`** - whether you call *from* Windows PowerShell or PowerShell Core.

Whether there is a good *technical* reason for this behavior or whether this is a *bug*, I have no clue.
Do let us know if you do.

In all other scenarios:

1. running as the current user as-is (the default)
2. impersonating a different user with `-Verb RunAsUser` (with an invariably interactive credentials prompt)
3. running non-interactively as a different user with `-Credential <PSCredential>`

the `-WorkingDirectory` parameter *is* respected.

However, if the (different) target user lacks the permissions to access the implied (current location) or explicitly specified working directory (via `-WorkingDirectory`), the current location defaults to `C:\` in case (2), and results in *failure* of the `Start-Process` command in case (3).

Comment: @Venryx: P.S.: Note that if `pwsh.exe` - PowerShell _Core_'s CLI - is started, `-WorkingDirectory` _is_ respected (and the caller's location is retained by default).