# How to start PowerShell script from BAT file with proper Working Directory?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to create bat script that can start PowerShell script named the same as bat file in proper working directotry.

This is what I got:

```
@ECHO OFF
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%~dpn0.ps1""' -WorkingDirectory '%~dp0' -Verb RunAs}"
PAUSE
```

Passing working directory this way does not work.

How to make script that will pass proper working directroy and also command line arguments?

Comment: It works for me but in the case `'%~dp0'` evaluates to a directory with a space in it, it  won't. For this situation you need to triple double quote the working directory: `"""%~dp0"""`

Comment: You can't set an initial working directory for the process when elevating - it will default to `System32` (or `SysWOW64` for 32-bit process). This is by design.

Comment: What about using `Set-Location (Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)` as the first command in `%~dpn0.ps1` ?

Comment: Correct - that would be the workaround. Setting a working directory when starting an elevated process has no effect.

Comment: @LotPings - If you can make answer from you comments I'll accept it.

Comment: As an aside: If you were to start PowerShell _Core_'s executable, `pwsh.exe`,  `-WorkingDirectory` _would_ be respected. Note that there's never a need for `& { ... }` inside a command string passed to `-Command` (the docs _mistakenly_ used to suggest that that's necessary).

Answer (score 10):

The `-WorkingDirectory` parameter doesn't work when using `-Verb RunAs`. Instead, you have to set the working directory by calling `cd` within a `-Command` string.

This is what I use: (cmd/batch-file command)

```
powershell -command "   Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs \""-Command `\""cd '%cd%'; & 'PathToPS1File';`\""\""   "
```

---

If you want to make a "Run script as admin" right-click command in Windows Explorer, create a new registry key at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Run with PowerShell (Admin)\Command`, and set its value to the command above -- except replacing `%cd%` with `%W`, and `PathToPS1File` with `%1` (if you want it to execute the right-clicked file).

Result: (Windows Explorer context-menu shell command)

```
powershell -command "   Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs \""-Command `\""cd '%W'; & '%1';`\""\""   "
```

EDIT: There's an alternative way to have the script be run as admin from Explorer, by using the "runas" sub-key: https://winaero.com/blog/run-as-administrator-context-menu-for-power-shell-ps1-files

---

If you want to run your script as admin from an existing powershell, remove the outer powershell call, replace `%W` with `$pwd`, replace `%1` with the ps1 file-path, and replace each `\""` with just `"`.

> Note: The `\""`'s are just escaped quotes, for when calling from the Windows shell/command-line (it's quote-handling is terrible). In this particular case, just `\"` should also work, but I use the more robust `\""` for easier extension.
>
> See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31413730/2441655

Result: (PowerShell command)

```
Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs "-Command `"cd '$pwd'; & 'PathToPS1File';`""
```

---

> Important note: The commands above are assuming that your computer has already been configured to allow script execution. If that's not the case, you may need to add `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` to your powershell flags. (you may also want `-NoProfile` to [avoid running profile scripts](http://www.powertheshell.com/bp_noprofile))

Comment: Nice; however, it's problematic to use `'` for quoting filesystem paths, given that `'` is a legal filename character - better to use `"`. In the case of your last command this means:  `Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs "-Command cd \\`"$pwd\\`"; & \\`"PathToPS1File\\`""`

Comment: Is it possible to pass parameters to the .ps1 file to be executed with PathToPS1File?

Comment: Also trying to figure this out. I need arguments to be passed in to the script.

Answer (score 5):

A workaround is to let the PowerShell script change the directory to it's own origin with:

```
Set-Location (Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
```

as the first command.

As per [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)s hint: In PSv3+ use the simpler:

```
Set-Location -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot
```

Or use this directory to open adjacent files.

```
$MyDir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$Content = Get-Content (Join-Path $MyDir OtherFile.txt)
```