# How can I elevate Powershell while keeping the current working directory AND maintain all parameters passed to the script?

Tags: powershell, admin, elevation

```
function Test-IsAdministrator
{
    $Identity = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
    $Principal = New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($Identity)
    $Principal.IsInRole([System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
}

function Test-IsUacEnabled
{
    (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System).EnableLua -ne 0
}

if (!(Test-IsAdministrator))
{
    if (Test-IsUacEnabled)
    {
        [string[]]$argList = @('-NoProfile', '-NoExit', '-File', $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
        $argList += $MyInvocation.BoundParameters.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {"-$($_.Key)", "$($_.Value)"}
        $argList += $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments
        Start-Process PowerShell.exe -Verb Runas -WorkingDirectory $pwd -ArgumentList $argList 
        return
    }
    else
    {
        throw "You must be an administrator to run this script."
    }
}
```

If I run the script above, it successfully spawns another PowerShell instance with elevated privileges but the current working directory is lost and automatically set to `C:\Windows\System32`. Bound Parameters are also lost or incorrectly parsed.

After reading similar questions I learned that when using Start-Process with -Verb RunAs, the -WorkingDirectory argument is **only** honored if the target executable is a .NET executable. For some reason PowerShell 5 doesn't honor it:

> The problem exists at the level of the .NET API that PowerShell uses behind the scenes (see System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo), as of this writing (.NET 6.0.0-preview.4.21253.7).

Quote from [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711252/workingdirectory-does-not-work-when-verb-is-used):

> In practice - and the docs do not mention that - the -WorkingDirectory parameter is not respected if you start a process elevated (with administrative privileges, which is what -Verb RunAs - somewhat obscurely - does): the location defaults to $env:SYSTEMROOT\system32 (typically, C:\Windows\System32).

So the most common solution I've seen involves using -Command instead of -File. I.E:

```
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -Verb Runas -ArgumentList '-Command', 'cd C:\ws; & .\script.ps1'
```

This looks really hack-ish but works. The only problem is I can't manage to get an implementation that can pass both bound and unbound parameters to the script being called via -Command.

I am trying my hardest to find the most robust implementation of self-elevation possible so that I can nicely wrap it into a function (and eventually into a module I'm working on) such as `Request-AdminRights` which can then be cleanly called immediately in new scripts that require admin privileges and/or escalation. Pasting the same auto-elevation code at the beginning of every script that needs admin rights feels really sloppy.

I'm also concerned I might be overthinking things, and to just leave elevation to the script level instead of wrapping it into a function.

Any input at all is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>Note: On 15 Nov 2021 a bug was fixed in the code below in order to make it work properly with *advanced* scripts - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69979813/45375) for details.</sup>

The closest you can get to a ***robust*, *cross-platform* self-elevating script solution** that **supports**:

- both positional (unnamed) and named arguments

  - while preserving type fidelity *within the constraints of PowerShell's serialization* (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375))
- preserving the caller's working directory.
- On Unix-like platforms only: synchronous, same-window execution with exit-code reporting (via the standard `sudo` utility).

is the following monstrosity (I certainly wish this were easier):

- Note:

  - A **simpler, but *limited, Windows-only* alternative** is in the **bottom section**.
  - For (relative) brevity, I've omitted your `Test-IsUacEnabled` test, and simplified the test for whether the current session is already elevated to `[bool] (net.exe session 2>$null)`
  - You can drop everything between `# --- BEGIN: Helper function for self-elevation.` and `# --- END: Helper function for self-elevation.` into any script - right after the parameter declarations, if any - to make it self-elevating. Due to use of `-NoExit`, the code keeps the elevated window open after the reinvoked script exits.

    - If you find yourself in repeated need of self-elevation, in different scripts, you can copy the code into your [`$PROFILE` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) or - better suited to wider distribution - convert the *dynamic* (in-memory) module used below (via [`New-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-module)) into a regular *persisted* module that your scripts can (auto-)load. With the `Ensure-Elevated` function available available via an auto-loading module, all you need in a given script is to call `Ensure-Elevated`, without arguments (or with `-Verbose` for verbose output).

```bash
# Sample script parameter declarations.
# Note: Since there is no [CmdletBinding()] attribute and no [Parameter()] attributes,
#       the script also accepts *unbound* arguments.
param(
  [object] $First,
  [int] $Second,
  [array] $Third
)

# --- BEGIN: Helper function for self-elevation; reusable as-is.
# Define a dynamic (in-memory) module that exports a single function, Ensure-Elevated.
# Note: 
#  * In real life you would put this function in a regular, persisted module.
#  * Technically, 'Ensure' is not an approved verb, but it seems like the best fit.
$null = New-Module -Name "SelfElevation_$PID" -ScriptBlock {  
  function Ensure-Elevated {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()

    $isWin = $env:OS -eq 'Windows_NT'

    # Simply return, if already elevated.
    if (($isWin -and (net.exe session 2>$null)) -or (-not $isWin -and 0 -eq (id -u))) { 
      Write-Verbose "(Now) running as $(("superuser", "admin")[$isWin])."
      return 
    }

    # Get the relevant variable values from the calling script's scope.
    $scriptPath = $PSCmdlet.GetVariableValue('PSCommandPath')
    $scriptBoundParameters = $PSCmdlet.GetVariableValue('PSBoundParameters')
    $scriptArgs = $PSCmdlet.GetVariableValue('args')

    Write-Verbose ("This script, `"$scriptPath`", requires " + ("superuser privileges, ", "admin privileges, ")[$isWin] + ("re-invoking with sudo...", "re-invoking in a new window with elevation...")[$isWin])

    # Note: 
    #   * On Windows, the script invariably runs in a *new window*, and by design we let it run asynchronously, in a stay-open session.
    #   * On Unix, sudo runs in the *same window, synchronously*, and we return to the calling shell when the script exits.
    #   * -inputFormat xml -outputFormat xml are NOT used:
    #      * The use of -encodedArguments *implies* CLIXML serialization of the arguments; -inputFormat xml presumably only relates to *stdin* input.
    #      * On Unix, the CLIXML output created by -ouputFormat xml is not recognized by the calling PowerShell instance and passed through as text.
    #   * On Windows, the elevated session's working dir. is set to the same as the caller's (happens by default on Unix, and also in PS Core on Windows - but not in *WinPS*)
    
    # Determine the full path of the PowerShell executable running this session.
    # Note: The (obsolescent) ISE doesn't support the same CLI parameters as powershell.exe, so we use the latter.
    $psExe = (Get-Process -Id $PID).Path -replace '_ise(?=\.exe$)'

    if (0 -ne ($scriptBoundParameters.Count + $scriptArgs.Count)) {
      # ARGUMENTS WERE PASSED, so the CLI must be called with -encodedCommand and -encodedArguments, for robustness.

      # !! To work around a bug in the deserialization of [switch] instances, replace them with Boolean values.
      foreach ($key in @($scriptBoundParameters.Keys)) {
        if (($val = $scriptBoundParameters[$key]) -is [switch]) { $null = $scriptBoundParameters.Remove($key); $null = $scriptBoundParameters.Add($key, $val.IsPresent) }
      }
      # Note: If the enclosing script is non-advanced, *both*
      #       $scriptBoundParameters and $scriptArgs may be present.
      #       !! Be sure to pass @() when $args is $null (advanced script), otherwise a scalar $null will be passed on reinvocation.
      #       Use the same serialization depth as the remoting infrastructure (1).
      $serializedArgs = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize(($scriptBoundParameters, (@(), $scriptArgs)[$null -ne $scriptArgs]), 1)

      # The command that receives the (deserialized) arguments.
      # Note: Since the new window running the elevated session must remain open, we do *not* append `exit $LASTEXITCODE`, unlike on Unix.
      $cmd = 'param($bound, $positional) Set-Location "{0}"; & "{1}" @bound @positional' -f (Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath, $scriptPath
      if ($isWin) {
        Start-Process -Verb RunAs $psExe ('-NoExit -encodedCommand {0} -encodedArguments {1}' -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($cmd)), [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($serializedArgs)))
      }
      else {
        sudo $psExe -encodedCommand ([Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($cmd))) -encodedArguments ([Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($serializedArgs)))
      }

    }
    else {
      # NO ARGUMENTS were passed - simple reinvocation of the script with -c (-Command) is sufficient.
      # Note: While -f (-File) would normally be sufficient, it leaves $args undefined, which could cause the calling script to break.
      # Also, on WinPS we must set the working dir.

      if ($isWin) {
        Start-Process -Verb RunAs $psExe ('-NoExit -c Set-Location "{0}"; & "{1}"' -f (Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath, $scriptPath)
      }
      else {
        # Note: On Unix, the working directory is always automatically inherited.
        sudo $psExe -c "& `"$scriptPath`"; exit $LASTEXITCODE"
      }

    }

    # EXIT after reinvocation, passing the exit code through, if possible:
    # On Windows, since Start-Process was invoked asynchronously, all we can report is whether *it* failed on invocation.
    exit ($LASTEXITCODE, (1, 0)[$?])[$isWin]

  }

}
# --- END: Helper function for self-elevation; reusable as-is.

# Call the self-elevation helper function:
#  * If this session is already elevated, the call is a no-op and execution continues,
#    in the current console window.
#  * Otherwise, the function exits the script and re-invokes it with elevation,
#    passing all arguments through and preserving the working directory.
#  * On Windows:
#     * UAC will prompt for confirmation / adming credentials every time.
#     * Of technical necessity, the elevated session runs in a *new* console window,
#       asynchronously, and the window running the elevated session remains open.
#       Note: The new window is a regular *console window*, irrespective of the 
#             environment you're calling from (including Windows Terminal, VSCode,
#             or the (obsolescent) ISE).
#     * Due to running asynchronously in a new window, the calling session won't know 
#       the elevated script call's exit code.
#  * On Unix:
#     * The `sudo` utility used for elevation will prompt for a password,
#       and by default remembers it for 5 minutes for repeat invocations. 
#     * The elevated script runs in the *current* window, *synchronously*,
#       and $LASTEXITCODE reflects the elevated script's exit code.
#       That is, the elevated script runs to completion and only then
#       returns control to the non-elevated caller.
#       Note that $LASTEXITCODE is only meaningful if the elevated script
#       sets its intentionally, via `exit $n`.
# Omit -Verbose to suppress verbose output.
Ensure-Elevated -Verbose

# Getting here means running with elevation.

# For illustration:
# Print the arguments received, in diagnostic form, as well as 
# the current location.
Write-Verbose -Verbose '== Arguments received:'
[PSCustomObject] @{
  PSBoundParameters = $PSBoundParameters.GetEnumerator() | Select-Object Key, Value, @{ n='Type'; e={ $_.Value.GetType().Name } } | Out-String
  # Only applies to non-advanced scripts
  Args = $args | ForEach-Object { [pscustomobject] @{ Value = $_; Type = $_.GetType().Name } } | Out-String
  CurrentLocation = $PWD.ProviderPath
} | Format-List

exit  # Report an exit code.
```

**Sample call**:

If you save the above code to file `script.ps1` and invoke it as follows:

```bash
./script.ps1 -First (get-date) -Third  ('foo', 'bar') -Second 42  @{ unbound=1 } 'last unbound'
```

you'll see the following:

- In the non-elevated session, which triggers the UAC  / `sudo` password prompt (Windows example):

  ```bash
   Current location: C:\Users\jdoe\sample
   VERBOSE: This script, "C:\Users\jdoe\sample\script.ps1", requires admin privileges, re-invoking in a new window with elevation...
  ```
- In the elevated session (which on Unix runs transiently in the same window):

  ```bash
   VERBOSE: (Now) running as admin.
   VERBOSE: == Arguments received:

   PSBoundParameters : 
                       Key    Value                  Type
                      ---    -----                  ----
                       First  10/30/2021 12:30:08 PM DateTime
                       Third  {foo, bar}             Object[]
                       Second 42                     Int32


   Args              : 
                       Value        Type
                       -----        ----
                       {unbound}    Hashtable
                       last unbound String

   CurrentLocation   : C:\Users\jdoe\sample
  ```

---

##### *Simpler*, but *limited*, *Windows-only* alternative:

The following **may be sufficient in many situations on Windows**, but has the following ***limitations***:

- works on *Windows only*.
- does *not* preserve the caller's working dir.
- supports only .NET primitive data types as arguments.
- doesn't support *array* parameters.

The code between the lines that start with `# --- BEGIN:` and `# --- END:` is *reusable as-is*. That is, you can drop it into any script - right after the parameter declarations, if any - to make it self-elevating. Due to use of `-NoExit`, the code keeps the elevated window open after the reinvoked script exits.

```bash
# Sample script parameter declarations.
# Note: Since there is no [CmdletBinding()] attribute and no [Parameter()] attributes,
#       the script also accepts *unbound* arguments.
param(
  [object] $First,
  [int] $Second,
  [switch] $Third
)

# --- BEGIN: Helper code for self-elevation; reusable as-is.
if (-not (net session 2>$null)) { # Test if already elevated.
  # Encode the arguments given for a call vie the PowerShell CLI with -File
  $quotedsArgList = foreach ($p in $PSBoundParameters.GetEnumerator()) { 
    $p.Value.GetType() | wva
    if ($p.Value -is [switch]) {
      if (-not $p.Value) { '-{0}:$false' -f $p.Key }
      else { '-{0}' -f $p.Key }
      }
    else {
      '-{0}' -f $p.Key
      if ($p.Value -match ' ') { "`"$($p.Value)`"" } else { "$($p.Value)" } }
   }
  $quotedsArgList += foreach ($arg in $args) { if ($arg -match ' ') { "`"$arg`"" } else { "$arg" } }
  # Reinvoke with elevation, wait for process termination and pass the exit code through.
  $ps = Start-Process -Wait -PassThru -Verb RunAs (Get-Process -Id $PID).Path ('-NoExit -File "{0}" {1}' -f $PSCommandPath, ($quotedsArgList -join ' '))
  exit $ps.ExitCode
}
# --- END: Helper code for self-elevation; reusable as-is.


# Getting here means running with elevation.

# For illustration:
# Print the arguments received, in diagnostic form, as
# well as the current location.
Write-Verbose -Verbose '== Arguments received:'
[PSCustomObject] @{
  PSBoundParameters = $PSBoundParameters.GetEnumerator() | Select-Object Key, Value, @{ n='Type'; e={ $_.Value.GetType().Name } } | Out-String
  # Only applies to non-advanced scripts
  Args = $args | ForEach-Object { [pscustomobject] @{ Value = $_; Type = $_.GetType().Name } } | Out-String
  CurrentLocation = $PWD.ProviderPath
} | Format-List

exit  # Report an exit code.
```

Comment: Yes, hacks are required. There is no `$0` to pass the original command line as in most normal shells and also no facility in PowerShell to use one, if it existed. Leave it to Microsoft to make simple things hard and hard things even harder. Thanks for your comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a really short solution:

```
if (-Not ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] 'Administrator')) {
    if ([int](Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BuildNumber) -ge 6000) {
        $CommandLine = "-NoExit -c cd '$pwd'; & `"" + $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path + "`""
        Start-Process powershell -Verb runas -ArgumentList $CommandLine
        Exit
    }
}

#Elevated script content after that
```

Comment: Very cool! Going to add it to my personal module and test it out. Thanks so much for contributing.

Comment: Just tested it, unfortunately I'm getting a `ParserError`: `Missing expression after '&' in pipeline element.`

Comment: Just tested it again by copying out of my answer to ensure I didn't make a copy/paste error. It works for me! So please try it out again.
Working on version 5.1.19041.1682 (the command is $PSVersionTable to get the version)

Comment: How about ``$CommandLine = "-NoExit -c `"cd '$pwd'; & '" + $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path + "'`""``?

Comment: Note that your solution doesn't pass any parameters through (an explicit requirement stated in the question). A couple of asides: `'$pwd'` should be `\`"$pwd\`"` for robustness. In v3+ you can use `$PSCommandPath` instead of `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path`

Comment: Sorry, I meant ``\`"$pwd\`"``, because `"` chars. to be retained as part of the PowerShell code to execute must be ``\``-escaped to protect them from the initial command-line parsing. This escaping is also missing from the quotes you put around `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path`. It is unlikely to matter in practice, but not enclosing the overall `-Command` argument (positionally implied) in (unescaped) `"..."` makes the code subject to whitespace normalization.

Comment: In short: A robust solution that preserves the working directory - but does _not_ pass parameters through - would require:
``$CommandLine = "-NoExit -c `"cd \`"$pwd\`"; & \`"$PSCommandPath\`"`""``

Comment: Great! In a final adaptation, to preserve working directory and script arguments, was changing the Start-Process statement to: `Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell.exe -Verb Runas -ArgumentList "-NoExit -Command cd \`"$pwd\`" \`; $($MyInvocation.Line)"`.