# Can't call a Powershell script through the registry properly. A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$null'

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, contextmenu

Here is a simple test function called `RegistryBoundParams.ps1`:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]
    $Target,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [switch]
    $MySwitch
)

if(!(Test-IsAdmin)){
    Request-AdminRights -NoExit
    Exit
}

if($MySwitch){
    "Do something" | Out-Host
}else {
    "Do something else" | Out-Host
}

Show-AllArguments
```

If I call it via the PS terminal, everything works as expected:

Exact call: `C:\Tools\scripts> .\RegistryBoundParams.ps1 -Target "C:\Test\" -MySwitch`

[image]

[image]

If I call it through the registry (adding the command to a context menu), I get:

```
pwsh -noexit -file "C:\Tools\scripts\RegistryBoundParams.ps1" -Target "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" -MySwitch
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Plaintext of the error: `RegistryBoundParams.ps1: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$null'.`

Here's a reg file that shows exactly what I added in the registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\1_TestRegistry]
@="Test Powershell Script from Registry"
"Icon"="C:\\Tools\\icons\\apps\\Powershell 1.ico,0"
"NeverDefault"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\1_TestRegistry\command]
@="pwsh -noexit -file \"C:\\Tools\\scripts\\RegistryBoundParams.ps1\" -Target \"C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\python.exe\""
```

So somewhere along the lines $Null is being passed to the script, and I have no Idea why.

I could really, really use some help here.

Thanks so much for any guidance.

### Edit:

---

I found that if I add a new string variable called $catchall, the script works. I suspect that when being called from the registry it's appending a null value for some reason. Which is why the script works when I define an additional "catch all" variable.

This is definitely not an ideal solution at all, so I am still looking for a solution here. Really appreciate any help!

### Edit2:

---

It turns out that the `Request-AdminRights` script I was using that mklement0 authored had a bug that has now been fixed. Anyone who wants one-line self elevation with bound/unbound parameter support that's cross-platform... [go get it!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69775592/45375)

Comment: In the non-admin instance I get this: https://i.imgur.com/yKFKvOo.png


In the admin instance I get "RegistryBoundParams.ps1: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$null'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a (since-fixed) bug in the code that you based your self-elevating function `Request-AdminRights` on:

The bug was that in the case of an *advanced* script such as yours, `$args` - which is never bound in advanced scripts - was mistakenly serialized *as `$null`* instead of translated to `@()`, resulting in that `$null` getting passed as an extra argument on re-invocation.

If you redefine your `Request-AdminRights` function based on the now updated body of the `Ensure-Elevated` function in the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69775592/45375), your problem should go away - no need to modify the enclosing script.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. I modified your script very minimally to support a -NoExit switch. You can find it here: https://github.com/visusys/VSYSFileOps/blob/main/Public/Request-AdminRights.ps1