# Dot-sourcing a self-elevate script

Tags: powershell, elevated-privileges

I have a self elevate snippet which is quite wordy, so I decided instead of duplicating it at the top of every script that needs to be run as admin to move it into a separate .ps1:

```
function Switch-ToAdmin {
    # Self-elevate the script if required
    if (-not ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] 'Administrator')) {
        if ([int](Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BuildNumber) -ge 6000) {
            $Cmd = @(
                "-Command Set-Location `"$(Get-Location)`"; & `"$PSCommandPath`""
                "-$($PSBoundParameters.Keys)"
            )
            $ProcArgs = @{
                FilePath     = 'PowerShell.exe'
                Verb         = 'RunAs'
                ArgumentList = $Cmd
            }
            Start-Process @ProcArgs
            Exit
        }
    }
}
```

So for every script that needs elevation I'd prepend

```
. "$PSScriptRoot\self-elevate.ps1"
Switch-ToAdmin
# rest of script
```

Doing above successfully procs the UAC prompt, but the rest of the script won't get executed.
Is this sorta stuff disallowed?

Comment: You might want to check what file $PSCommandPath is pointing to.  I'm thinking you are elevating, and calling, "self-elevate.ps1" instead the calling script.

Comment: That is because the `Switch-ToAdmin` function starts a new session. In your `Switch-ToAdmin` script you need to find the caller, see [`Get-PSCallStack](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-pscallstack) and restart that.

Comment: Nice catch, @Darin - that's worthy of being written up as an answer, given that the behavior is counterintuitive.

Comment: Thanks folks. Swapping `$PSCommandPath` for `(Get-PSCallStack)[1].ScriptName` makes it successfully continue on to the rest of the script! I'm not actually sure if using a literal index (`[1]`) is the proper way of doing it but it seems to do the job.. Open to suggestions though! Slightly off-topic but `self-elevate.ps1` is actually in a different directory, and similarly swapping `Get-Location` for `Split-Path (Get-PSCallStack)[1].ScriptName` makes that work as well.

Comment: I agree with @mklement0 the two commenters should probably expand their comment to an answer cuz that was pretty much the culprit.

Comment: @gargoylebident, `(Get-PSCallStack)[1].ScriptName`, despite the property's name, reports a full path.`$(Get-Location)` (which you could simplify to `$PWD`) should be fine, assuming you want to preserve the _current location_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Darin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4190564/darin) and [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron) have provided the crucial pointers:

- Darin points out that **the [automatic `$PSCommandPath` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pscommandpath) variable in your `Switch-ToAdmin` function does *not* contain the full path of the script from which the function is *called*, but that of the script in which the function is *defined***, even if that script's definitions are loaded directly into the scope of your main script via `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-).

  - The same applies analogously to the automatic **[`$PSScriptRoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psscriptroot)** variable, which reflects the defining script's full *directory* path.
- Also, more generally, the [automatic `$PSBoundParameters` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psboundparameters) inside a function reflects *that function's* bound parameters, not its enclosing *script*'s.
- iRon points out that the **[`Get-PSCallStack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-pscallstack)** cmdlet **can be used to get information about a script's *callers***, starting at index `1`; the first object returned - index `0`, when `Get-PSCallStack` output is captured in an array, represents the *current* command. Index `1` therefore refers to the *immediate* caller, which from the perspective of your dot-sourced script is your main script.

Therefore:

- Replace `$PSCommandPath` with **`$MyInvocation.PSCommandPath`**, via the automatic [`$MyInvocation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#myinvocation) variable. `$MyInvocation.PSCommandPath` truly reflects the *caller's* full script path, irrespective of where the called function was defined.

  - Alternatively, use `(Get-PSCallStack)[1].ScriptName`, which despite what the property name suggests, returns the *full path* of the calling script too.
- Replace `$PSBoundParameters` with 
  **`(Get-PSCallStack)[1].InvocationInfo.BoundParameters`**

  - Note that there's also `(Get-PSCallStack)[1].Arguments`, but it seems to contain a single *string* only, containing a representation of all arguments that is only semi-structured and therefore doesn't allow robust reconstruction of the individual parameters.

---

As an aside:

Even if `$PSBoundParameters` contained the intended information, `"-$($PSBoundParameters.Keys)"` would only succeed in passing the bound parameters through if your script defines only *one* parameter, if that parameter is a `[switch]` parameter, and if it is actually passed in every invocation.

Passing arguments through *robustly* in this context is hard to do, and has inherent limitations - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69775592/45375) for a - complex - attempt to make it work as well as possible.