# run powershell as administrator from python

Tags: python, powershell

I have a PowerShell script which look like this:

```
# Define time for report (default is 1 day)
$startDate = (get-date).AddDays(-10)

# Store successful logon events from security logs with the specified dates and workstation/IP in an array
# foreach ($DC in $DCs){
# $slogonevents = Get-Eventlog -LogName Security -ComputerName $DC.Hostname -after $startDate | where {$_.eventID -eq 4624 }
# }

$slogonevents = Get-Eventlog -LogName Security -after $startDate | where {$_.eventID -eq 4624 }

# Crawl through events; print all logon history with type, date/time, status, account name, computer and IP address if user logged on remotely

  $(foreach ($e in $slogonevents){
    # Logon Successful Events
    # Local (Logon Type 2)
    if (($e.EventID -eq 4624 ) -and ($e.ReplacementStrings[8] -eq 2)){
      write-host "Type: Local Logon`tDate: "$e.TimeGenerated "`tStatus: Success`tUser: "$e.ReplacementStrings[5] "`tWorkstation: "$e.ReplacementStrings[11]
    }
    # Remote (Logon Type 10)
    if (($e.EventID -eq 4624 ) -and ($e.ReplacementStrings[8] -eq 10)){
      write-host "Type: Remote Logon`tDate: "$e.TimeGenerated "`tStatus: Success`tUser: "$e.ReplacementStrings[5] "`tWorkstation: "$e.ReplacementStrings[11] "`tIP Address: "$e.ReplacementStrings[18]
    }
}) *>&1 > D:\Cyber_security\Python\test.txt
```

I want to run this script from python. this script is saved in my D drive.My python script is:

```
import subprocess, sys

p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", 
              "D:\Cyber_security\Python\login.ps1"], 
              stdout=sys.stdout)
p.communicate()
```

but it doesn't work. I need to run powershell as administrator but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *nest* `powershell.exe` calls:

- An outer call that calls PowerShell's [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) cmdlet with `-Verb RunAs`, which allows running *any* executable with elevation.
- Since what you want to run with elevation is a `.ps1` script, it must be called via `powershell.exe`, the Windows PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), as in your own attempt, except that you explicitly need to incorporate a [`Set-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location) call to ensure that the script runs in the same working dir. as the caller (`C:\Windows\System32` is the default in Windows PowerShell when `Start-Process -Verb RunAs` is used).

  - If you don't need this, or if you're using `pwsh.exe`, the CLI of the cross-platform [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) edition (which now retains the working dir. by default), the inner call can be simplified to (replace `powershell.exe` with `pwsh.exe` in both places to use PowerShell 7+):
  - `powershell.exe -Args '-noprofile -file D:\Cyber_security\Python\login.ps1'`

```
# See bottom section if you also want to get the exit code of 
# the elevated process.
p = subprocess.Popen(
  [
    "powershell.exe", 
    "-noprofile", "-c",
    r"""
    Start-Process -Verb RunAs -Wait powershell.exe -Args "
      -noprofile -c Set-Location \`"$PWD\`"; & D:\Cyber_security\Python\login.ps1
      "
    """
  ],
  stdout=sys.stdout
)
p.communicate()
```

Note:

- Running a process with elevation:

  - involves an interactive UAC confirmation / credentials prompt that cannot be bypassed (unless UAC is turned off, which would be ill-advised)
  - invariably runs in a *new window*.
  - prevents *direct* capture of the elevated process' output streams; you'll have to redirect to (temporary) *files* instead, which you can do with `Start-Process`' 
    `-RedirectStandardOutput` / `-RedirectStandardError` parameters.
- CLI parameters `-noprofile` and `-c` were added: `-noprofile` suppresses loading of PowerShell's [profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles), and `-c` (`-Command`) explicitly indicates that what follows are PowerShell commands to execute.
- `-Wait` was added to the `Start-Process` call above so as to make the outer `powershell.exe` call wait for the elevated process to exit before continuing.
- You don't strictly need `powershell.exe` + `Start-Process -Verb RunAs` for launching an elevated process, but it is the most convenient option.

  - A Python-based solution is possible, but involves fairly complex use of the WinAPI - see [this blog post](https://yeahexp.com/how-to-run-a-subprocess-with-admin-permission/)
  - Note that while you can technically use `runas.exe /user:Administrator` utility to create an elevated session, doing so (a) only works with precisely that account, i.e. the built-in account named `Adminstrator`, and that account is often disabled in practice (it is disabled by default).
- An alternative approach would be to modify the `.ps1` file to *self-elevate* on demand (or use a helper `.ps1` file that does that) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69775592/45375)

---

**Variation that also gets the *exit code* of the elevated process:**

If your `.ps1` script uses the `exit` statement in order to deliberately report a (process) exit code that signals success vs. failure and you want to query that exit code, a bit more work is needed:

- `Start-Process` `-PassThru` switch outputs a process-information object representing the newly launched process, whose `.ExitCode` property reports the process exit code (after termination).
- Due to how the `-c` / `-Command` CLI parameter works, the inner `powershell.exe` call must use `exit $LASTEXITCODE` explicitly to relay the script's exit code as the elevated process' exit code.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
  [
    "powershell.exe", 
    "-noprofile", "-c",
    r"""
    exit (
      Start-Process -Verb RunAs -PassThru -Wait powershell.exe -Args "
        -noprofile -c Set-Location \`"$PWD\`"; & C:\Users\jdoe\Desktop\pg\pg.ps1; exit `$LASTEXITCODE
      "
    ).ExitCode
    """
  ],
  stdout=sys.stdout
)
p.communicate()

print('Terminated with exit code ' + str(p.returncode))
```