# How to elevate to SYSTEM - needed to execute RunAsUser module

Tags: powershell, elevated-privileges, privilege-elevation

I need to execute a PS which creates registry entries for the current user and right after restarts a service (admin rights needed). I found a module called RunAsUser that seems to do this very nicely.
https://github.com/KelvinTegelaar/RunAsUser

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name "NuGet" -RequiredVersion "2.8.5.201" -Force -Confirm:$False
install-module RunAsUser -Confirm:$False -Force
$scriptblock = { 
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Palo Alto Networks\GlobalProtect\Settings\" -Name LastUrl -Value "vpn.xxx.yyy"
}
invoke-ascurrentuser -scriptblock $scriptblock
Restart-Service -Name PanGPS
```

But when I run it with a user with local admin rights I get the following error asking for SYSTEM rights.

```
invoke-ascurrentuser : Not running with correct privilege. You must run this script as system or have the SeDelegateSessionUserImpersonatePrivilege token. At C:\Temp\MoveFromVPN2toVPN.ps1:30 char:1
+ invoke-ascurrentuser -scriptblock $scriptblock
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-AsCurrentUser
```

Any idea on how to become SYSTEM? I managed to obtain a shell with SYSTEM using psexec command.

> psexec.exe -i -s powershell.exe

From there my script works flawless, but I would like to make it programmatically directly inside my script.

Any idea how to do this?

thanks.

Comment: You don't elevate to system. System is a different `user` or in some points of view a `computer` Account. The command name `invoke-ascurrentuser` implies that the current user won't change. So that seems Not to be your solution. Scheduled tasks can be executed as `system` and can be triggered by a logon event. Just use system as username in the task

Answer (score 0):

Building on [An-dir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17277716/an-dir)'s helpful comment:

- The `SYSTEM` (`NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`) account is a highly privileged, built-in user account that is *not* designed for interactive use.

  - The `Invoke-AsCurrentUser` function from the third-party [`RunAsUser`](https://github.com/KelvinTegelaar/RunAsUser) module you link to is designed to run PowerShell code *as the current user* from a process that already *is* running as `SYSTEM`, as happens in the context of RMM (Remote Monitoring and Management) systems.
  - While [`psexec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) `-s` indeed can run a process as `SYSTEM` (and can therefore also run a PowerShell script via `powershell.exe`, the Windows PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)), there is rarely a need for it, and I don't think you need it either. Crucially, `psexec -s` requires calling from a process that is *already elevated* (see next point).
- It sounds like you're simply trying to run your script *with elevation* (with administrative privileges), which happens in the context of a specific *administrator* user account, but only *when explicitly requested*, using one of the following:

  - Starting an elevated PowerShell session *interactively*, e.g. by right-clicking the PowerShell icon in the taskbar or the Start Menu and selecting `Run as Adminstrator`, at which point a [UAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) dialog is presented in order to confirm the intent to elevate (or, if the current user isn't an administrator, to enter an administrator's credentials).
  - Starting a PowerShell session *programmatically*, e.g. by using [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) `-Verb Runas powershell.exe`
  - If you want your script to automatically *elevate itself* if needed, i.e. to re-invoke itself with elevation if invoked from a non-elevated process, use the technique shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69775592/45375); note, however, that the UAC dialog still has to be confirmed (unless UAC is disabled entirely, which is strongly discouraged).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your comments.
Finally I managed to do it without additional modules. as the script is executed from InTune as SYSTEM, it can write directly into the registry hive of the connected user.

```
$a = New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -Name HKU -Root HKEY_USERS
$username = Gwmi -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | select username
$objuser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($username.username)
$sid = $objuser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])

$Path = "HKU:\$sid\Software\Palo Alto Networks\GlobalProtect\Settings\XXX.yyy"
if( -not (Test-Path -Path $Path -PathType Container) )
{
    New-Item -Path $Path
}
Remove-PSDrive -Name HKU 

Restart-Service -Name PanGPS
```