# Windows error while running powershell script to set chrome as default browser

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, default-browser

```
$browserPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
$browserKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command\"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $browserKey -Name "(Default)" -Value $browserPath
```

This PowerShell script successfully ran on Windows 10 22H2 for your colleague but failed to work when you tried it on a VMware environment with same version.

Despite attempting various scripts, I encountered errors that caused the default browser to revert back to Microsoft Edge (MSEDGE). I am seeking assistance in creating a PowerShell script that can effectively function on Windows versions ranging from Windows 10 to Windows 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The registry key you're targeting would *not* be sufficient to change a user's default web browser.
- Microsoft is trying to prevent the ability to *programmatically* change the default web browser, by not disclosing a hash algorithm that is used to validate the relevant registry settings.

  - The idea is that changing the default browser should be a *deliberate, interactive* user action only.

---

- However, a *third-party utility*, `SetDefaultBrowser.exe`, has figured out this algorithm, and therefore allows fully automated changes to the user's default web browsers:

  - For background information and a download link, see [this blog post](https://kolbi.cz/blog/2017/11/10/setdefaultbrowser-set-the-default-browser-per-user-on-windows-10-and-server-2016-build-1607/).

    - Note: There is an *obsolete* warning in the linked blog post about needing a *portable* browser installation - it can safely be ignored.
  - Alternatively, as you've discovered, if you have [Chocolatey](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/setdefaultbrowser) installed, you can install [`SetDefaultBrowser.exe`](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/setdefaultbrowser) as follows:

    ```
    choco install setdefaultbrowser -y
    ```
- If downloading a third-party utility is *not* an option, the next best - but suboptimal - solution is to use *GUI scripting*:

  - See [this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/1803346/139307).
  - Note that GUI scripting is (a) not robust and limited in terms of what environments it can run from and (b) can break *over time*, if the GUI changes.

Assuming you have downloaded `SetDefaultBrowser.exe` and have placed in a directory listed in your `$env:PATH` environment variable, you can make Google Chrome your default browser as follows:

```
SetDefaultBrowser chrome
```

- The above uses a built-in shortcut for Google Chrome; other available shortcuts as of v1.5: `edge`, `ie`, `iexplore`
- The above is the equivalent of the following:

  ```
  SetDefaultBrowser HKLM 'Google Chrome'
  ```

  - `HKLM` (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`) indicates the registry hive in which information about the targeted browser is stored; the other possible value is `HKCU` (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER`)
  - Running `SetDefaultBrowser` without arguments will show you what browsers are locally installed, and will list them by registry hive (e.g. `HKLM`) and display name (e.g. `Google Chrome` (as well as full executable path), which are the two pieces of information you need to pass to make that browser the default

    - E.g., to make a user-level installation of the Brave browser the default (the alphanumeric suffix may vary, but can be gleaned from the output of an argument-less call):

      ```
        SetDefaultBrowser.exe HKCU Brave.4E65X2HYVK4P2KKNWFWGNPUBYY
      ```

---

The following is a **self-contained solution that installs both Chocolatey and `SetDefaultBrowser.exe` on demand, and then changes the default browser to Google Chrome**.

Note:

- The script must be run *with elevation* (as administrator).

  - This is required for the on-demand installations only; `SetDefaultBrowser.exe` itself, once installed, does *not* require elevation.
- Therefore, a possible refinement of the script is to *self-elevate on demand, only when necessary*, such as using the technique shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69775592/45375).

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator

# Set this to $false to silence the Write-Verbose calls below.
$verbose = $true

# Install SetDefaultBrowswer.exe, if necessary.
if (-not (Get-Command -ErrorAction Ignore SetDefaultBrowser.exe)) {

  # Install Chocolatey first, if necessary.
  if (-not (Get-Command  -ErrorAction Ignore choco.exe)) {
    Write-Verbose -Verbose:$verbose "Installing Chocolatey (this will take a while)..."
    # Note: We silence success output, Write-Host and Write-Warning messages. The progress display from the Expand-Archive
    #       call can only be silenced if $ProgressPreference is *globally* set
    $prevProgressPref = $global:ProgressPreference; $global:ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
    try {
      Invoke-RestMethod -ErrorAction Stop https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 | Invoke-Expression >$null 3>$null 6>$null
      if (-not (Get-Command  -ErrorAction Ignore choco.exe)) { throw "Installation of Chocolatey failed." }
    } finally {
      $global:ProgressPreference = $prevProgressPref
    }
  }

  Write-Verbose -Verbose:$verbose "Installing SetDefaultBrowser..."
  # Note: Place the -y (for automated installation) *at the end* of the command line.
  choco install SetDefaultBrowser -y >$null
  if ($LASTEXITCODE) { Write-Error "Installation of SetDefaultBrowser failed."; exit $LASTEXITCODE }

  # Refresh the environment so that SetDefaultBrowser.exe can be called by name only.
  # Do so via Chocolatey's Update-SessionEnvironment cmdlet, which is part of the Chocolatey profile module.
  $env:ChocolateyInstall = Convert-Path "$((Get-Command choco.exe).Path)\..\.."   
  Import-Module -ErrorAction Stop "$env:ChocolateyInstall\helpers\chocolateyProfile.psm1"
  Update-SessionEnvironment

}

Write-Verbose -Verbose:$verbose "Calling SetDefaultBrowser.exe ..."

# Switch to Google Chrome as the default browser.
SetDefaultBrowser chrome
if ($LASTEXITCODE) { exit $LASTEXITCODE }

Write-Verbose -Verbose:$verbose "The user's default browser was successfully changed to Google Chrome."
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (!(Test-Path "$env:ProgramData\chocolatey\choco.exe")) {
        Write-Host "Installing Chocolatey..."

        # Download and run the Chocolatey installation script
        Invoke-Expression ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

        Write-Host "Chocolatey installed successfully."
    } else {
        Write-Host "Chocolatey is already installed."
    }
}

function Install-Package {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$packageName
    )

    choco install $packageName -y
}

function Set-ChromeAsDefaultBrowser {
    $setBrowserPath = "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\setdefaultbrowser\tools\SetDefaultBrowser\SetDefaultBrowser.exe"
    if (Test-Path $setBrowserPath) {
        & $setBrowserPath HKLM "Google Chrome"
        Write-Host "Chrome successfully made default browser."
    } else {
        Write-Host "Failed to find SetDefaultBrowser executable."
    }
}

# Main script execution
Install-Chocolatey
Install-Package "setdefaultbrowser"
Set-ChromeAsDefaultBrowser
```